# PHP slowlog empty even though PHP-FPM says it's logging

Tags: php, docker, php-fpm, php7

I have PHP-FPM listening on a Unix domain socket and I've configured the `www` pool (the only one present) with the following values:

```
slowlog = /$pool.log.slow
request_slowlog_timeout = 10s
```

and just for testing I've set max_execution_time in `php.ini` to 20 seconds. Then I created a test script:

```
<?php

while(1){
  $i++;
}

?>
```

Then accessed it via web browser. The script eventually times out due to `max_execution_time` but the log remains empty:

```
root@b7e4a919c988:/var/www/html# ll /www.log.slow 
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 www-data root 0 Jan  4 21:31 /www.log.slow
```

The PHP-FPM log, though seems to indicate that it was expecting to log the slow run:

```
[04-Jan-2018 21:37:28] WARNING: [pool www] child 9382, script '/var/www/html/test.php' (request: "GET /test.php") executing too slow (13.061999 sec), logging
```

I've tried a variety of things such as using `sleep(10000)` or putting the `while` loop in a function (just in case it couldn't build a stack trace) but nothing seems to get it to print the backtrace to the log. The existence of the logfile itself also seems to indicate FPM is expecting to write slow requests.

At this point I just don't know what else to check.

Comment: did you restart the php-fpm service after changing the settings and the script?

Comment: @EvilTorbalan Yep. At first I was just doing `kill -SIGUSR2` of the master process but after I started having trouble I switched to just killing all pids and starting `php-fpm7.0` again

Comment: You can use service php-fpm restart or systemctl restart php-fpm depending on the linux variant you have. or /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart if its really old ;)

Comment: try lowering request_slowlog_timeout to 1s to see if anything gets logged.

Comment: @EvilTorbalan This is inside a container so the scripts don't work. I've also tried from a fresh container where `php-fpm` had never been ran before. I've also lowered it down to `1s` and `5s` all with identical behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after much to-do I finally figured out the problem. The issue is that on Linux, PHP-FPM uses `SYS_PTRACE` to trace the worker processes (I'm guessing this is how it retrieves the trace data) but `docker` containers don't allow this capability by default.

Once I ran the docker container with the `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` option and configured the two `www.conf` settings mention in the OP (`slowlog` and `request_slowlog_timeout`).

Contrary to other SO answers I've seen posted, I never had to enable `catch_workers_output` to get it to work.

The above script generates this output to slowlog:

```
[09-Jan-2018 17:30:39]  [pool www] pid 9382                
script_filename = /var/www/html/work.php
```

But to generate a more realistic function trace I wrote this little number:

```
<?php

function callsSlowFunc(){

  for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++){
    slowFunc();
  }

}

function slowFunc(){

  for ($j=0; $j <= 50000000; $j++){
    $hey="there";
  }

}

callsSlowFunc();
```

Which results in this function trace being generated:

```
[09-Jan-2018 17:40:49]  [pool www] pid 9382
script_filename = /var/www/html/work.php
[0x00007fee53613150] slowFunc() /var/www/html/work.php:6
[0x00007fee536130a0] callsSlowFunc() /var/www/html/work.php:19
```